# Search for keyword in an unsigned char in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My main idea is to search in the payload for a specific word, whether it's there or not. I wrote this code to search for a keyword (`search_for_string`) in an `unsigned char` (`foo`).

**The problem is that the `foo` is a pointer to an `unsigned char`. How can I save the value of the pointer `foo` in a new string variable an use it in the `strstr`?**

For the iptables, I have setup this rule via the terminal:

```
sudo iptables -t filter -I OUTPUT --proto tcp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
```

This is my test nping before I run the code:

```
sudo nping -c 10 --tcp -p 80,433 --data-string helloWorld 185.60.216.35
```

To compile the file I use additionally:

```
gcc -o output input.c -lnetfilter_queue -lnfnetlink
```

*The code file*

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <libnetfilter_queue/libnetfilter_queue.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

static int cb(struct nfq_q_handle *qh, struct nfgenmsg *nfmsg,
              struct nfq_data *nfa, void *data) {
    size_t payloadLen = 0;
    unsigned char *foo;
    payloadLen = nfq_get_payload(nfa, &foo);

    struct iphdr *ip_header;
    ip_header = (struct iphdr *)foo;

    struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr *ph;
    ph = nfq_get_msg_packet_hdr(nfa);
    char search_for_string[] = "helloWorld";

    if (strstr((char *)foo, search_for_string)) {
       printf("\nThe Payload contains the keyword.");
   } else {
       printf("\nPayload does not contain the keyword.");
   }
```

Comment: Show the definition of `foo`.

Comment: what do you mean, _foo_ is a `char**` ? in that case just do `if (strstr(*foo, ...` or `char * str = *foo; if (strstr(str, ...`. Note that `in string (foo)` and `foo is a pointer to an array` are not compatible

Comment: When I do `if (strstr(*foo, ... ` 
I get the error message:
passing argument 1 of ‘strstr’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       if (strstr(*foo, search_for_string)) {

Comment: When `foo` is defined with `unsigned char *foo;`, it is not a pointer to an array. It is a pointer to an `unsigned char`. Its value may point to the first character of an array. You could pass `(char *) foo` to `strstr`.

Comment: Thank you @Eric Postpiscil! I tried it out, but get "Segmentation fault"

Comment: @Codestructor: Then likely it is pointing to something improper. You should provide an [mcve].

Comment: @Codestructor: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55088452/edit) to add these details.  Code in comments is very hard to read, as you'll notice.

Comment: You cannot use `strstr` on binary data.  Network packets are not NUL-terminated, instead you know the length.  You need a search function that works on counted strings not terminated strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foo is probably equal to NULL which will cause a SEGFAULT when passed to strstr. You should add a NULL check before calling strstr.

nfq_get_payload will return -1 on error so you should use a signed type instead of size_t for payloadLen and check for that as well.

Here's a potential solution:

```
static int cb(struct nfq_q_handle *qh, struct nfgenmsg *nfmsg, struct 
nfq_data *nfa, void *data) {

ssize_t payloadLen;                          //Note: Signed type
unsigned char *foo = NULL;                   //Note: Init with NULL
payloadLen = nfq_get_payload(nfa, &foo);

if(payloadLen < 0){
   //TODO: Do something...
}

struct iphdr *ip_header;
ip_header = (struct iphdr *)foo;

struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr *ph;
ph = nfq_get_msg_packet_hdr(nfa);
char search_for_string[] = "helloWorld";

if((foo == NULL) || (payloadLen < 0)){
   //TODO: print something if you want
}
else if (memmem((void*)foo, payloadLen, search_for_string, strlen(search_for_string))) 
   {
       printf("\nThe Payload contains the keyword.");
   } 
else 
   {
       printf("\nPayload does not contain the keyword.");
   }
```

Comment: Thank you everybody! It works perfectly now!
Just a note: I had to include 
'#define _GNU_SOURCE' at the top of the file, before all the headers.